# How to write INSERT… ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE as Separate Queries?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I'm trying to avoid the massiveness autoincrement (a little bit here and there is fine) when i do an insert on duplicate key.

I wrote it out as separate queries.
Check if record exist using key (can be primary or foreign key).
If exist, update.
If not, insert.

Which kinds works except that not all my schema are structured the same way so for one of my tables, it rewrote all the records that had the same foreign key because it was not unique (but I do not have this problem when i do insert on duplicate key).

So I was wondering there's a good way to recreate the Insert Update On Duplicate Key as separate queries so it can avoid the unnecessary auto increments.

Comment: "So I was wondering there's a good way to recreate the Insert Update On Duplicate Key as separate queries so it can avoid the unnecessary auto increments." Maybe if you do it inside a TRANSACTION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IODKU requires a `UNIQUE` key, usually *not* an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

IODKU, *if not already in a transaction*, can be simulated with

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;   -- note
if row exists
    UPDATE ...;
else
    INSERT ...;
COMMIT;
```